# How to check if file is in use in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

How can I check if the excel file on which I am working (manipulating its data, deleting it or overwriting it) is in use by another program? And how to release it from the same?

Please guide me using C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attempt to open in with flags "for writing". If it fails, the file is "taken" by some other process.

```
FileStream fileStream = null;

try
{
    fileStream =
        new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
    // The access requested is not permitted by the operating system
    // for the specified path, such as when access is Write or ReadWrite
    // and the file or directory is set for read-only access. 
}
finally
{
    if (fileStream != null)
        fileStream.Close ();
}
```

P.S. Just found a very similar question with basically the same answer:

[C#: Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/c-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

Comment: So you mean by catching exceptions? But any other cleaner way than doing it by exceptions?

Comment: Great it working for me , but wonder there in no other way to perform this... well Thanks But Insted of UnauthorizedAccessException  exception I used IOException in my code

Comment: Yes, with exceptions better check out which one is throw in different scenarios. I just read the MSDN description and picked up the one that looked suitable for this example.